# Is there a way to call a function through a variable?

Tags: python, function

I'm really new to Python but I'm trying to do something definitely above my skill level.
Is it possible to calla a function though a variable? For example,

```
def one():
    print("this is a function")
progress = "one"
progress()
```

with the intention of calling the function "one()".

Is this possible?

Comment: `one` *is a variable*. `"one"` is not a function, it is a string. In python, functions are just objects like anything else. So of course, you can do `progress = one`

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure that's a good duplicate target, I think the OP simply wants `one = progress`, there has to be a more relevant question somewhere...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: that is not at all clear. They used a string, the other answer explains how to use a string to find and call a function. There simply multiple interpretations possible here, and so we can either close as 'unclear' or as a duplicate. The duplicate at least provides more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take off the double quotes around `"one"` and you should be good.

```
def one():
    print("this is a function")

progress = one
progress()
```